# Java- How to fail a program if some condition does match?

Tags: java

I have a condition where i am checking for something. I want to fail this program if that condition does not match. How can i fail a program or throw an exception if it is does not match a condition.

what i did

```
String workStream="Default";
String workSteam2;

for(String s : s1){
    if(s.equals(workStream)){
        workSteam2=workStream;
    }else{
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: By fail, you want to exit or you want to notify the user?

Comment: You are already throwing an exception

Comment: you can make your own custom exception and throw it or you can use system.exit(0) to stop the application

Comment: If s1 is a string array, just make a list of it and use the contains function to check if workSteam is there and give a message. if(Array.AsList(s1).Contains(workSteam)) { // show message }

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an exception, you have to catch it Otherwise your program will just crash. Put your code in a try/catch block and handle the exception in your catch.

```
try{
    for(String s : s1){
        if(s.equals(workStream)){
            workSteam2=workStream;
        }else{
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    // handle your exception here
}
```

If you want to quit your program, you can use `System.exit(0)` as well.

Comment: i dont want to catch it but complier is giving me error that i have to handle it. I want to give a message that you haven't met the condition , so program is failing.

Comment: Catching it is the same thing as handling it.

Comment: If you want to validate a condition, then you should consider using while loops and booleans rather than throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
throw new RuntimeException();
```

RuntimeExceptions do not have to be handled, and if not caught it will terminate the program.

Answer (score -1):

```
    String workStream="Default";
    String workSteam2;
    
    for(String s : s1){
    if(!(s.equals(workStream))){
    throw new Exception();
    workSteam2=workStream;
    }
        }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.